# Separating SVG sprite sheet using html css

Tags: html, css, svg, sprite-sheet

I'm currently trying to split up an .svg sprite sheet into its individual sprites. The svg sheet is a single svg sheet and not several cojoined svg files. I originally attempted this with a .png file and it correctly isolated the first image in the sprite sheet. Upon switching to the svg version the width and height tags now represent different properties.

.png = size of view window on the sprite sheet

.svg = size of entire sprite sheet

```
<span class="Lettuce"> </span>

.Lettuce {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 512px;
  height: 512px;
  background: url(Ingredients.svg) 0 0;
}
```

I'm just trying to display the individual sprites of the sprite sheet and scale them up from their 12x12 resolution, so I'm open to another approach. I am not trying to display an animation.

If the images are successfully isolated is there a way to scale them up outside of the id. E.g. scale via a surrounding div or a class.

Edit:
This is what i'm getting with a .svg file
[.svg implementation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PQe2i.png)

This is what i'm getting with a .png file
[.png impementation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dmotg.png)

Note: the width/height are set to 12px for the .png and 512 for the .svg. The reason is stated up top.

I would like the .png result but to scale up the image size from 12 px to something like 200px without scaling issues, hence why i'm trying to use .svg.

Comment: You could supply a viewBox e.g. Ingredients.svg#svgView(viewBox(0,200,1000,1000)) adjust the values as appropriate.

Comment: It's not very clear what you want to achieve. Do you think 'background-size' could help?